# Integrate a younger qt version in an older yocto release

Tags: embedded, yocto, compatibility, qt5

Our project is based on the meanwhile outdated yocto *warrior*, which was first modified by the vendor of our SoM. Then we integrated the FreeScale/NXP kernel into it because the mainline kernel did not support GPU functionality we needed.

It has been quite a ride to get this working, but now there is need to switch from qt 5.12 as included in our *warrior* to qt 5.15 (LTS). We want to avoid switching to a new yocto release, but only changing the checkout of the meta-qt5 layer leads to `bitbake` problems like

```
ERROR: ParseError at meta-qt5/recipes-qt/qt5/qtwebengine_git.bb:83: Could not inherit file classes/features_check.bbclass
```

and I expect this to be only the first of a series of incompatibilities, so I'm asking myself what would be the best approach to the problem.

Should I start my own meta-qt5 branch, changing the recipes to use qt 5.15.8 and only  cherry-pick commits from current meta-qt5 branches?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue at the moment (bsp based on warrior and I need the Qt 5.15.2) and these are what I've already tried and discovered:

- There is a version of [meta-qt5](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/log/?h=upstream/jansa/master-5.15) with the **5.15** that is compatible with **warrior**. However this version uses classes and features that aren't available in the **warrior** (such as: features_check, mime-xdg and so fourth), so I don't get a logic how it should work.
- The first yocto version that contains a feature set that required by the new meta-qt5 is **dunfell**, so I've tried to update other layers to revisions that are compatible with **dunfell**, but probably half of layers from my project don't provide version that are compatible with this yocto release.

So, in conclusion, what options do we have (or what I already know):

- We can update layers(poky, meta-qt5 and other) that supports and compatible with newer release and port layers that don't do it manually;
- (Warning: can be a bad idea) Exclude meta-qt5 from the project, build image and generate SDK and then cross-compile Qt from sources using cross-compile and rootfs from the project SDK.

**I've not found other solutions yet. If you have already solved this problem or you still are trying to do it, please contact me on this email: svforpromotion@gmail.com**

P.S. I'm unable to comment questions on the SE due to a lack of reputation, so sorry for using answers section. If we'll find a solution with OP then I'll update answer with it.

Comment: »There is no known way to achieve this« is a sad, but valid answer in my eyes. My upvote should give you some reputation. I will update here as soon as we make any progress.

Comment: Which Version do you mean? I see a commit https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/commit/?h=upstream/jansa/master-5.15&id=5a328383122c7d82b096b1b090a850e14d6fa311 from 2019 claiming warrior compatibility, but this was back at Qt 5.12. Could it be they simply forgot to remove the compatibility flag?

Comment: I meant [this tag/commit - upstream/jansa/master-5.15](https://code.qt.io/cgit/yocto/meta-qt5.git/commit/conf?h=upstream/jansa/master-5.15&id=00c9491b1024594b10b78a689a68e871ca57902c). If you'll open the 'tree' page and check a layer.conf then you should see: LAYERSERIES_COMPAT_qt5-layer = "sumo thud warrior zeus". However, as I said, the **'warrior'** doesn't contain required features in the poky layer and I think, there will be a lot other problems (as you also said).

Comment: @Philippos Also, I've just created [issue](https://github.com/meta-qt5/meta-qt5/issues/460) on the meta-qt5 GitHub page, so you can subscribe on it and maybe comment that you have noticed the same problem. Anyway, I'll let you know here about updates.

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://embeddeduse.com/2022/04/11/building-qt-6-2-for-old-yocto-versions/) gives tutorial how to simply build your Qt version of choice outside the `bitbake` system, so it can be integrated into your yocto build. I just don't understand if this can be used along with recipes depending on Qt.

Currently, I neither have the urge to do so nor do I find the time to test. Once I reproduced it successfully, I might update and accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to modify your esdk, which includes meta-qt5 layer.
Instructions [can be found here.](https://support.xilinx.com/s/question/0D54U00006tZyzPSAS/replace-or-update-existing-yocto-metalayer-in-petalinux-project?language=en_US)

However you will face many issues, as the latest meta-qt5 version compatible with yocto warrior is 5.14.2. I would recommend staying in something officially supported, otherwhise you will have to fix too many build errors.